# Make a progress bar that activate on click for a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I realize there is a similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019381/using-jquery-javascript-to-turn-a-button-into-a-progress-bar), but the code is not working when I try to adapt it to my case. So here are some details:

In an idle game I'm making, the user can make multiple action but I would like him to know if the action is in progress or not. So when he would click my div, its background could fill up like a progress bar.

my html:

```
<div class="button" onClick="makeMoney()" id="makeMoney">
<span>Go To Work</span></div>
```

my JS:

```
function makeMoney() {
var btn = document.getElementById("makeMoney");
if (btn.getAttribute('disabled') == 'disabled') {
   return;
}
btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
setTimeout(function () {
    money += job;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled')
}, 10000)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example on how you can show progress bar. Its very basic and does not use any API. ( except for basic jquery ).

HTML :

```
<input type="button" class="button" onClick="makeMoney()" id="makeMoney" value="Action">
</input>
<div id="divfillmeUp" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
 function makeMoney() {      
        $("#makeMoney").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        fillAgain();
    }

    function fillAgain() {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            if($("#divfillmeUp").find('div').length <= 10)
            {
                $("#divfillmeUp").append("<div style='background-color: red; width: 10%; height: 1%;float: left'></div>");
                fillAgain();
            }
        },2000)
    }
```

Hope it helps.